# Python guessing game, lottery numbers but using def

Tags: python, random

So my task was to make a lottery function, but the instructor only provides half the code when explaining and going through my resources i was unable to find proper examples on how to complete it aside from this part.

```
import random

def user(startval, endval, numberpicked):
    somelist = []
    while len(somelist) < numberpicked:
        newnum = random.randint(startval,endval)
        if newnum not in print("Not valid, try again"):

    return

i am aware i need to append at some point, but im racking my brain trying to understand how i know if i have created a function that generates a list of lottery numbers. they tried to provide help with the following but it did not make much sense.

import random

def myfuncname(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3):
mytemplistname = []
do your loop to generate the number, see if it is in mytemplistname,
append it if need be and you could do something like
while len(mytemplistname) < parameter3:
#generate random number
#if new number not in mytemplist name, then append it to the
list

#sort the list
#return the list

#here you would actually call your function and store the returned list in
a variable etc
```

Comment: Please learn how to separate plain text and code correctly in markdown before asking. Also we don't help you for not yet implemented code, you might want to check in our [help] what and what not you can ask here.

Comment: (I find it least error prone to fence code blocks in lines containing just `~~~`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

def func(startval,endval,p):
   some_list=[]
   while(p!=0):
       x=random.randint(startval,endval)
       if x not in some_list:
           some_list.append(x)
           p=p-1
    some_list.sort()
    return some_list
```

Try and check if this works out for you!

Comment: Welcome to code review, where we review working code to provide suggestions on how to improve the code. This answer is an alternate solution and is not a code review. A code review provides at least one insightful observation about the code. It would also be better to not provide answers for questions that have more than one down vote (less than -2) because these questions might be closed as off-topic as this one has. This question was off-topic because the code wasn't working.